# Pourquoi ne pas créer un podcast french SE ? - Why not create a podcast for french SE ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Pourquoi ne pas créer un podcast pour french SE ?! où on parle chaque semaine des questions posées sur le site ? et des réponses ... un podcast collaboratif, c'est une idée géniale !

---

Why not create a podcast for french SE? where talking weekly questions on the site? and answers ... a collaborative podcast, it's a great idea!

Comment: Ask Different ran a podcast for a while: http://apple.blogoverflow.com/category/podcast/

Comment: Pourquoi pas… s'il y a des volontaires.

Comment: Je suis le premier volontaire :)

Comment: Alors? ç'en est où?