# Faire venir un peu plus de gens sur le site, pour sortir de la phase bêta: une suggestion possible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, beta-phase

En parcourant les vieux sujets, j'ai vu que le fait que le site soit toujours en bêta tient au fait qu'il n'y a [pas forcément suffisamment de trafic en regard des exigences de l'hébergeur Stack Exchange](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327/dur%C3%A9e-de-la-b%C3%AAta-duration-of-the-beta).

Je trouve ce site un peu tristounet, ce qui ferait peut-être venir des gens, c'est le fait d'apprendre de nouvelles choses sur le français, d'une façon ludique. 
Là, il y a une réelle valeur ajoutée par rapport aux très très nombreux autres sites concernant l'usage du français.
L'événement spécial fournirait aussi peut-être un prétexte pour faire la promotion de ce site, en parler un peu, sur le réseau Stack Exchange, et encourager des anglophones qui n'ont peut-être que de très petits rudiments de français, à venir poser des questions. 
Du genre: Ah tiens, mais oui je vais aller voir, et en profiter pour poser une question sur les 2 mots que je connais en français.

Cet événement serait que chaque semaine, on "habillerait" le site aux "couleurs" d'un écrivain français, en mettant son portrait (casser la monotonie de l'habillage) et on proposerait des infos, des bounties (quel terme en français?), ou autres "gamification" (fr: ludification) à déterminer. Gagner un badge pour être venu tous les jours ou juste une fois pendant la courte période de l'événement.

L'idée m'est venue en lisant [ce sujet](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/site-design-should-we-honour-joachim-du-bellay), qui proposait un habillage aux "couleurs" de Joachim du Bellay, mais les réponses faites étaient: pourquoi lui et pas un autre?
Et bien, pourquoi pas une poignée d'autres dans ce cas?

Si nous voulons attirer des gens, il faut ludifier. C'est bien pour ça que le système des chapeaux de noël existe.

En parcourant les sujets anciens, j'ai aussi remarqué qu'il y avait souvent de bonnes idées, [par exemple](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/516/une-comp%C3%A9tition-d%C3%A9criture-sur-m%C3%A9ta-a-writing-competition-on-meta) ou [encore](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/536/pourquoi-ne-pas-cr%C3%A9er-un-podcast-french-se-why-not-create-a-podcast-for-fren), mais la communauté semble un peu léthargique, les idées sont appréciées mais pas souvent mises en pratique. Il faut se bouger un peu.

Comment: Des idées intéressantes, merci. L'habillage ça impliquerait un contrôle sur l'habillage justement... je pense qu'il y a peu de flexibilité avec l’identité graphique des sites, mais qui sait...

Comment: Je ne sais pas trop comment ça fonctionne, quel est le degré de liberté. J'ai vu que certains sites personnalisaient leur habillage, et qu'il en avait été question ici, mais l'idée n'a pas abouti visiblement. Je ne sais pas s'il est possible d'afficher une image, de l'écrivain. Mais si ce n'est pas possible, il y a quand même de la matière si on veut s'amuser un peu. Quizzes ou autre.

Comment: Je pense qu'on a le contrôle de la page d'[aide](http://french.stackexchange.com/help), suite à une [requête](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/613/3177), et le texte en français y est plutôt récent...

Comment: Généralement, le style des sites est créé par l'équipe de design de Stack Overflow quand un site passe la période beta, et reste tel quel ensuite, à moins de demandes précises. À ma connaissance, aucun site n'a de contrôle sur le style.